# E is measurable, then measure of E is the sum of the inner measure of a subset of E and the outer measure of the complement of the subset in E

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If E is a measurable and A is any subset of E, show that $|E|=|A|_i+|E-A|_e$
where |E| is the measure of of E, $|A|_i$ is the inner measure of A, and $|E-A|_e$ is the outer measure of $E-A$.

I have proved $|E|\geq|A|_i+|E-A|_e$, but I can't seem to figure out $\leq$ part of the proof.

I just need hints. Please don't solve it for me. Thank you!