# Measure is Sum of Inner Measure and Outer Measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In [E is measurable, then measure of E is the sum of the inner measure of a subset of E and the outer measure of the complement of the subset in E](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644685/e-is-measurable-then-measure-of-e-is-the-sum-of-the-inner-measure-of-a-subset-o) it is asked to prove $|E|=|A|_i+|E-A|_e$ where $A \subset E$ is any subset of $E$, does not necessarily measurable. I am curious about the answer of this problem since I also haven't managed to solve it yet. Thank you.